# ¿Por qué se llamaba "cucaracha martín" a una mujer morena?

Tags: vocabulario, etimología, definiciones, modismos

En el [DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BXESa9T) he encontrado con sorpresa que **cucaracha martín** es

> 1. f. desus. Mujer morena.

Igualmente aparece en [Wiktionary](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/cucaracha):

> cucaracha martín: Mujer de piel morena.

y buscando he encontrado que aparece recogido en 1611 por [**Covarrubias**](https://books.google.es/books?id=YsRKAAAAcAAJ)

> A la muger que es morena suelen dezir cucaracha martin, &c.

y Fernando Iwasaki, en [**"La caja de pan duro"**](https://books.google.es/books?isbn=8415370822) (2013) repite la definición de Covarrubias, añadiendo que es un requiebro o piropo.

La asociación "cucaracha" con "morena" o "de piel morena" no parece plantear dificultades, ya que muchas cucarachas son de color obscuro, pero lo que no entiendo es de dónde procede lo de **martín** y por qué el conjunto "*cucaracha martín*" se aplicaba a las mujeres.

Comment: Me ha fascinado el descubrimiento. He encontrado la expresión en [este artículo](http://www.historicalsoundscapes.com/evento/325/sevilla/en). Puede que tenga origen en una canción callejera del siglo XVI.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Así es, la única alusión que encontré es la de la carta de la Inquisición mencionada allí, donde "Martín" se refiere a Lutero. Cuesta saber cuál de los sentidos precedió al otro. Mirando el [Nuevo tesoro lexicográfico](http://ntlle.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltGUILoginNtlle) de la RAE, parece que "cucaracha" significaba insectos como los cienpiés y las cochinillas (1786 TERREROS Y PANDO), y que el lexicógrafo John Stevens estaba, ya en 1706, tan confundido como nosotros: "this is a by word they say to a brown Woman; the reason I cannot find, unless it be because the _Cucarachas_ are brown".

Comment: @JMVanPelt pero me entra una duda: cuando Covarrubias dice "a la mujer que es morena", ¿se refiere a morena de piel o a morena de pelo? Porque no lo indica, al igual que el DRAE, y puede que los libros que dicen que es morena de piel simplemente lo hayan supuesto, al igual que quien editó el Wikcionario.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Buen punto, no lo había pensado. Para sumar a la confusión, descubrí que existe un cuento folclórico del Caribe llamado ["La cucaracha Martina"](http://www.sabelotodo.org/literatura/infantil/cucarachitamartina.html), del cual [al menos una fuente](https://books.google.com/books?id=STjcB_f7CVcC&pg=PA155&dq=%22cucarachita+martina%22#v=onepage&q=%22cucarachita%20martina%22&f=false) afirma que tiene origen precolombino. Obviamente, los nombres son españoles; otra vez, cabe preguntarse, si es que hay relación, cuál antecedió al otro.

Comment: @user13560 no tiene por qué. El que tradujo "mujer morena" por "brown woman" bien pudo suponer que se refería al tono de piel.

Comment: Se me ocurre que puede haber un nexo entre el cuento de la cucaracha Martina y la copla que cita la Inquisición, ya que la del cuento era muy pulcra y atildada y la copla dice "cuán pulidica" va; tratándose de un cuento caribeño y estando ese lugar lleno de esclavos negros, habría surgido una conexión (con lo cual se referiría a mujeres morenas de piel y no de cabello). Lo que no entiendo, de ser así, es que Covarrubias diga "Martín" en vez de "Martina" y nadie lo haya notado en siglos, cosa que me hace dudar un poco de la hipótesis.

Comment: También es posible que refiera más bien a las trabajadoras tabaqueras.  Tabaco cucaracha es un tipo especial de tabaco, por lo cual sería posible que una mujer que laboraba produciendo tal tipo de tabaco podría llegar a llamarse mujer cucaracha.  De la asociación con el color de la piel tendría que ser por ser esas esclavas (teniendo en cuenta Cuba y el Caribe como punto central del mercado tabaquero).  Ya que nadie indica que el uso sea despectivo o peyorativo, paréceme más probable que con alguna conexión con el insecto, que en su caso debería de ser bastante insultante.

Comment: @guifa la teoría es muy interesante, pero ¿y lo de "martín"? ¿Alguna marca de tabaco?

Answer (score 3):

Parece haber una cierta confusión con respecto a este término. Por un lado, están los que citan a Covarrubias (incluyendo la versión actual del DRAE), que dicen que el término es "cucaracha martín". Por otro lado, hay algunos que defienden que el término es "cucaracha martina". Buscando en el [fichero general](http://www.rae.es/recursos/banco-de-datos/fichero-general) de la RAE el término "cucaracha" hay notas en ambos bandos. Con respecto al segundo bando tenemos a [Fernando Ortiz](http://www.rae.es/recursos/banco-de-datos/corde), nacido en Cuba en 1881, del cual hay [una ficha](http://web.frl.es/FICHERO/FICHERO/LETRA_C/LETRA_C_II_PDF/CUCARACHA/00000294.pdf) (PDF) en la que se recoge lo siguiente:

> En Cuba decimos "cucarachita martina" a un personaje del folklore infantil. Es locución traída de Andalucía, donde se dice cariñosamente "cucarachita martina" a la "mujer morena" [hace referencia a la RAE aquí]. Pero debe de ser corrupción de "cucarachita mandinga". Así se dice todavía hoy en Centro América y debió de decirse en todas las Españas cuando las correrías conquistadoras por Guinea e Indias, que bien pudo ser también la época.

Buscando "cucarachita" en el [CORDE](http://www.rae.es/recursos/banco-de-datos/corde) aparece por fin la expresión:

> Pero su mina más productiva fué la custodia. Pedía por ésta cuarenta mil duros, y perdía plata, según él. Propuso al arzobispo Las Heras que la comprase para la Catedral de Lima; mas el coro de canónigos declaró que no estaba la cucarachita Martina para cintajos ni abalorios.
>
> - Ricardo Palma, "Tradiciones peruanas, octava serie", Perú (1891)

No me da la sensación de que se refiera a una mujer morena aquí. En todo caso, es probable que la expresión en realidad fuese "cucarachita Martina", si es cierto que [el cuento](http://www.sabelotodo.org/literatura/infantil/cucarachitamartina.html) tiene un origen antiguo (tal y como afirma [la fuente](https://books.google.com/books?id=STjcB_f7CVcC&pg=PA155&dq=%22cucarachita%20martina%22#v=onepage&q=%22cucarachita%20martina%22&f=false) de JMVanPelt) y que fuese conocido en siglo XVI, o que sea una corrupción de "mandinga":

> **[mandinga](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OA2fQbK)**
>
> 1. adj. Dicho de una persona: De un pueblo que habita en el Senegal, Costa de Marfil, Guinea, Guinea-Bisáu y Malí. U. t. c. s.
> 2. adj. Perteneciente o relativo a los mandingas.

El término vendría originado en la época de la esclavitud negra en España, como afirma el propio Fernando Ortiz en [esta otra ficha](http://web.frl.es/FICHERO/FICHERO/LETRA_C/LETRA_C_II_PDF/CUCARACHA/00000295.pdf) (PDF). Pero entonces originalmente pudo tener un sentido peyorativo.

Sobre la teoría de que en realidad era "cucaracha Martín", lo único que existe es [una referencia a una canción popular callejera](http://www.historicalsoundscapes.com/evento/325/sevilla/en) del siglo XVI y con origen en Sevilla, que decía "cucaracha Martín cuán pulidica andáis". No parece fácil encontrar una conexión, dado que aquí "Martín" hacía referencia a Lutero. En todo caso, "pulidica" aquí significaría "adornada, hermosa" según los diccionarios de la época, lo que deja lugar a la interpretación: es posible que la expresión pasara a designar una mujer hermosa morena de pelo, dado el color de las cucarachas y el adjetivo "pulidica" que acompañaba a la canción. Es incluso posible que si para entonces ya existía el cuento de la cucaracha Martina, que lo de "cucaracha Martín" fuese un juego de palabras basado en el cuento. Y así todo estaría conectado.

Resumiendo: los orígenes de la expresión no están demasiado claros, pero se pueden hacer conjeturas. Habría que ver cuál podría ser el origen del cuento de la cucaracha Martina para darle un poco de coherencia a todo, aunque es interesante notar que ambas ramas parecen apuntar al mismo sitio: Andalucía.

Comment: Es interesante la conexión entre que Ortiz diga que la expresión viene de Andalucía, y que la copla de "Cucaracha Martín" contra Lutero haya sido recogida en Sevilla.

Comment: @JMVanPelt cierto, no había caído, parece que todas las pistas conducen al mismo sitio.